# Error loading merged table from power BI to SSIS using Power query source?

Tags: sql-server, ssis, powerbi

I have two tables in Power BI (list and status) and I merged them into a single table (merge 1)using an inner join. after merging, I tried to load it (merge 1)into a SQL database using SSIS where I used a power query source. But error shows Token semicolon expected(start position10.1, End position 10.4)

I copied the query from Power bi Query editor by copying the table

As my original query is quite long I will attach a sample another simple query

// list

```
let
    Source = Csv.Document(File.Contents("C:\Users\patha\Desktop\list.txt"),[Delimiter=",", Columns=3, Encoding=1252, QuoteStyle=QuoteStyle.None]),
    #"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(Source, [PromoteAllScalars=true]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Promoted Headers",{{"fruit", type text}, {"place", type text}, {"price", Int64.Type}})
in
    #"Changed Type"
```

// status

```
let
    Source = Csv.Document(File.Contents("C:\Users\patha\Desktop\status.txt"),[Delimiter=",", Columns=2, Encoding=1252, QuoteStyle=QuoteStyle.None]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Column1", type text}, {"Column2", type text}}),
    #"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(#"Changed Type", [PromoteAllScalars=true]),
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Promoted Headers",{{"fruit", type text}, {"status", type text}})
in
    #"Changed Type1"
```

// Merge1

```
let
    Source = Table.NestedJoin(list, {"fruit"}, status, {"fruit"}, "status", JoinKind.Inner),
    #"Expanded status" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(Source, "status", {"status"}, {"status.1"}),
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Expanded status",{{"status.1", "status"}})
in
    #"Renamed Columns"
```

Please help me to resolve this issue. This happens in case of any merged table. Thank you

Comment: Why use Power Query? Why not use SSIS to load the CSV files, Join them using SSIS and move the results to the DB table? Are you copying Merge 1 into the siss as it doesn't have the dependant steps?

Comment: No,I have got actually big tables which I already standardized using Power BI and I did merge of that tables in Power BI too. But I wonder why I couldn't directly load it (merged table) into SSIS ??